# string returns assigned value instead of database data

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I try to receive a nickname from an user from the database, but it always returns the value which is assigned to the string nickname variable.

```
    public string GetEigenaarBlog(int gebruikerid)
    {
        string nickname = null;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT Nickname FROM Gebruiker WHERE GebruikerID = :gebruikerid";
            command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("gebruikerid", gebruikerid));
            nickname = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return nickname;
    }
```

**This is my code in the form:**

```
    private void listBoxBerichten_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
        Blog blog = (Blog)lb.Items[lb.SelectedIndex];
        int blogid = blog.BlogID;

        geselecteerdeBlog = dk.GetGeselecteerdeBlog(blogid);

        string blogeigenaar;
        foreach (Blog b in geselecteerdeBlog)
        {
            blogeigenaar = dk.GetEigenaarBlog(b.GebruikerID); //This is the method where is the problem
            tbGeblogd.Text = Convert.ToString(b.Datum);
            tbTitel.Text = b.Titel;
            tbDoor.Text = blogeigenaar;
            tbBlogInhoud.Text = b.Inhoud;
        }
    }
```

The parameter works, it reads that parameter from the form.

When I change `string nickname = null` to `string nickname = 'hello'` then it returns nickname as hello. So it returns the assigned value. When I keep `string nickname = null` then it returns null

What am I doing wrong? the SQL-query is right, and the user exist in the database. I'm not getting any errors or warnings.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10623100/342740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a datareader this way. You will have to loop through the datareader and get the data. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.aspx for more info.

Instead of

```
nickname = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader());
```

try this

```
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
nickname = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    nickname = Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know a reader was a must while retreiving one record! :)

Comment: To retrieve one record you can always use ExecuteScalar. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: I tried executescalar! That's why I didn't use executereader. But that also didn't work!

Comment: Did you mean that you first tried ExecuteScalar and when it did not work you tried ExecuteReader?

Comment: Yes.... I was getting the same issue with bot of them... But executereader with while-read() works now. But I will try executescalar again.

Comment: Wow... executescalar works now too. This is very weird! But thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Your code needs to be changed in this way

```
public string GetEigenaarBlog(int gebruikerid)
{
    string nickname = null;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT Nickname FROM Gebruiker WHERE GebruikerID = :gebruikerid";
        command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("gebruikerid", gebruikerid));
        OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        // Now try to read from the reader (and position the reader on the first record returned)
        if(reader.Read())
            nickname = reader[0].ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    return nickname;
```

The ExecuteReader method returns an OracleDataReader and this object needs to be positioned on the first record before trying to read from it. Thus you need to call the Read method, and if that method returns true you could read the string.

Said that however, when you have a query that returns just one row and one column then a very fast approach is through the ExecuteScalar method

```
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT Nickname FROM Gebruiker WHERE GebruikerID = :gebruikerid";
        command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("gebruikerid", gebruikerid));

        // ExecuteScalar returns the value of the first row/first column, or null if 
        // there is no record to return. Need to be carefull here
        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if(result != null)
            nickname = result.ToString();
```

As a side note, I can't see the full code, but it seems that you keep a global connection object.
This is considered a bad and needless practice because the [Connection Pooling mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featConnecting.htm#i1006393) could do a better work to keep the connection objects ready to use

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know a reader was a must while retreiving one record! :)

Comment: In your case I would Use the ExecuteScalar method and avoid the overhead of an unnecessary object and method call